# Parse: reference randomly generated objectID

Tags: swift, pointers, parse-platform

When I save in Parse, it generates a random objectId for each save.

I want to automatically get this objectId before I save, since I have another class with pictures that has a pointer back to the objectId.  Currently I have it pointed to objectId "xyz" (see code).

How do I reference the random objectId being created before the save?

```
//I want objectId:"xyz" to be the random generated objectId in NewLog class.  
//Guessing something like objectId:"NewLog.randomgeneratedobjectid"??
let pointer = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"NewLog", objectId: "xyz")
```

In the class NewLog, the left column, objectId, generates a random objectId each time something is saved to Parse:

[image: The first column, objectID, is randomized]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the other class, instead of referencing the `objectId` of `NewLog`, you should use a pointer to the `NewLog` object. Check the documentation here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-relational-data.

Comment: Hey Eric, how do I query this pointer?  Say, I wanted to access the data of the row the pointer is referencing to...

Comment: Check out this section of the query documentation: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-relational-queries. You'll want to make sure your query is set up to include the pointed-to object, something like this: `query.includeKey("newLog")`, assuming the `NewLog` object is under the key `newLog`. Then you can access the `NewLog` object like any other property of your other object, something like `let newLog = object["newLog"]`.